# Нужна ли запятая после слова "вот" в данной ситуации?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в данной ситуации?

> Я готовлюсь. Вот(,) вчера на сноуборде катался.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

В данной ситуации возможны оба варианта:

(1) Я готовлюсь. **Вот вчера** на сноуборде катался. Указательная частица ВОТ **относится к наречию  "вчера"**, на которое падает ударение, пауза отсутствует.

(1) Я готовлюсь. **Вот,  вчера** на сноуборде катался. Указательная частица ВОТ **подтверждает ситуацию** (я действительно готовлюсь), пауза после частицы.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна, т. к. здесь *вот* — частица с указательным значением.

> Запятая ставится после слова *вот*, если следующее за ним предложение раскрывает его конкретный смысл: *Вот,  можете полюбоваться на своего
>   сынка;  Вот,  возьмите эту книгу на добрую память*.
>
> Но: *Вот аптека; Вот раздался удар грома; Вот взгляните; Вот ещё что
>   затеял!; Вот оно что*, где *вот* — частица с указательным значением.
>
> В отдельных случаях возможны варианты пунктуации; ср.:
>
> *Вот,  кончились наши запасы* (пауза после *вот*). — *Вот кончились наши
>   запасы*;
>
> *Ну вот,  теперь можно поговорить о делах*. — *Ну  вот  теперь можно
>   поговорить о делах*.

Подробнее [здесь](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827513.html#id-%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%97%D0%94%D0%95%D0%9B8%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85-%C2%A729%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B02).
P. S. Возможно, варианты есть, но большинство подобных случаев не обособляется (см. [Корпус](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E2%EE%F2%2C%20%E2%F7%E5%F0%E0)).